# how to show the hidden <dl> elements one by one or all at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am trying to show the hidden `<dl>` tags when you click "View More".  In this example I have 3 `<dl>` elements, but It could be more or less.

**HTML**

```
<dl class="dl">
<dt><b>Name:</b></dt>
    <dd>My name</dd>   
<dt><b>Department</b></dt>
    <dd>My department</dd>  
<dt><b>Email</b></dt>
    <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>

<br/>

<dl class="dl">
   <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>My name</dd>   
<dt>Department</dt>
    <dd>My department</dd>  
<dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>

<br/>
<dl class="dl">
<dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>My name</dd>   
<dt>Department</dt>
    <dd>My department</dd>  
<dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(function(){
 $("#dl").each(function(){
 var $dd = $(this).nextUntil("dt"), $this;
 $dd.filter(":gt(0)").hide();


 if($dd.length > 1){  
     $dd.last().after($("<a href='#'>View More</a>").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
     $(this).text($(this).text() == "View More"?"Hide More":"View More")

  .prevAll("dt:first").nextUntil("dt").filter(":gt(2):not('a')").toggle()
     }));
 }
 });
   });
```

The problem right now is that when I click "View More" nothing happens, in other words, the other 2 `<dl>` elements don't show up.  And What I would like to happen is that when you click **View More** the other `<dl>` show up and when you click **Hide More** hide the one that were hidden before clicking **Show More**

I could do it either way: show the rest of the `<dl>` elements one by one or display the rest of the `<dl>` elements all at once.  Or/And hide the elements one by one or all at the same time.

here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc0mq4n9/11/)

Comment: If you had to chose, what behaviour would you prefer when clicking "view more"

Comment: when you click 'view more' show the rest of the `<dl>` elements, in this case, show the other 2 `<dl>`

Comment: you can't set same id for multiple elements, id must be unique

Comment: @JoshHarrison show them one by one will be great to display one by one until display all, and then show the "Hide More" option when everything is showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following working code. I have modified your code a bit instead of id i am using class (As @Ricardo Pontual stated you can't use same id multiple times in a document).

**HTML**

```
<dl class="dl">
   <dt><b>Name:</b></dt>
   <dd>My name</dd>
   <dt><b>Department</b></dt>
   <dd>My department</dd>
   <dt><b>Email</b></dt>
   <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>
<br/>
<dl class="dl">
 <dt>Name:</dt>
 <dd>My name</dd>
 <dt>Department</dt>
 <dd>My department</dd>
 <dt>Email</dt>
 <dd>My Email change1</dd>
</dl>
<br/>
<dl class="dl">
  <dt>Name:</dt>
  <dd>My name</dd>
  <dt>Department</dt>
  <dd>My department</dd>
  <dt>Email</dt>
  <dd>My Email change</dd>
</dl>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
      var select = $('.dl');
       select.filter(":gt(0)").hide();
       if(select.length > 1){  
       $('.dl:last').after($("<a href='#'>View      
       More</a>").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).text($(this).text() == "View More"?"Hide More":"View
  More").prevAll("dl").nextUntil("dt").filter(":gt(0):not('a')").toggle()
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: This code does the same as mine. And mine is a better answer because I'm not hitting the DOM to simply add an a tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I think this may work for you.

Note: as others have noted you shouldn't be using the same id more than once as they are meant to be unique.

HTML

```
<dl class="always-show">
    <dt><b>Name:</b></dt>
        <dd>My name</dd>   
    <dt><b>Department</b></dt>
        <dd>My department</dd>  
    <dt><b>Email</b></dt>
        <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>

<br/>

<dl class="hidden">
   <dt>Name:</dt>
        <dd>My name</dd>   
    <dt>Department</dt>
        <dd>My department</dd>  
    <dt>Email</dt>
        <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>

<br/>
<dl class="hidden">
    <dt>Name:</dt>
        <dd>My name</dd>   
    <dt>Department</dt>
        <dd>My department</dd>  
    <dt>Email</dt>
        <dd>My Email</dd>
</dl>

<a href='#'>View More</a>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var that = $(this);

        $.each($('dl').not('.always-show'), function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('hidden')){
                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                that.text('Hide');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                that.text('View More');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc0mq4n9/6/)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that is affecting others `<dl>` tag in the website.   For example, I have 2 columns right and left column.  In left column I have `<dl>` element, in the right column I could have multiple `<dl>` elements, so this answer is affecting both left and right column, and it should have effect only in the right column =/

Comment: Well, you'd have to work a bit more to get that effect. For instance adding a data attribute that declares which column it is in. But this is the base of what you're looking to do, right?

Comment: And besides... your question specifically says "all at the same time"
My answer should have been accepted. Driving me nuts trying to get rep here.

Comment: yes i got it, thanks for your response. the `<dl>`1 couldn't use two different class because they are in a loop.  If i use two different class then I would have to use lf and else statements in order to make sure to get the first one `always-show` and the rest `hidden`  (which is not bad, but more code)

Comment: Ok, so then .not(':first-child') when referencing the parent element. That would also solve the issue of separate columns.

Comment: I understand.  your answer is not wrong that is why I gave you +1, but if other users check my question and they see your answer as the correct answer they might think that your answer fit my question, however if you copy and paste the `js` from the `correct` answer , the code work perfectly without touching the `html` or `css`.  However, your time is very valuable for users like me, who are starting learning js/jquery ;)

Comment: Fair enough! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I made few changes to your existing code and removed some logic which i believe was either not needed or was overkill. Also, for toggling the text name, i used a toggleClass() expression ( somehow I think doing a text comparison is not an optimal way ).

```
 $("#dl").each(function(){
     var $dl = $(this);
     var $dd = $(this).nextUntil("dt"), $this;
     $dd.filter(":gt(0)").hide();

     if($dd.length > 1){  
         $dd.last().after($("<a href='#' class='visible'>View More</a>").click(function(e){             
              e.preventDefault();            
              $dl.siblings().toggle();
              $(this).text($(this).attr("class") == "visible"? "Hide More":"View More");
                $(this).toggleClass('visible invisible'); 
                $(this).show();
              })
         )           

     }
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hc0mq4n9/8/